# How can i get Equivalent method of HttpwebRequest in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

As we all know HttpwebRequest loads another page behind the scenes without redirecting the client to the other page.

How can I get this functionality using Javascript/Jquery?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
debugger;
var ip = '<%= Request.UserHostAddress%>';
var location = window.location.href;
var Browser = BrowserDetect.browser;
var Version = BrowserDetect.version;
var Os = BrowserDetect.OS;
var SendItems = 'Ip=' + ip + '&location=' + location + '&Browser=' + Browser   + '&Version=' + Version + '&Os=' + Os;
var HttpWebReq = ?
```

I want to pass these values as a query string to the other page :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cross domain example by using yql,

```
var url = 'xyz.com'; // website you want to scrape
var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from html where url="' + url + '"') + '&format=json&callback=?';  
$.getJSON(yql,function(data){
    if (data.results[0]){  
        console.log(data = data.results[0].replace(/<script[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/script>/gi, ''));  // The scraped data (the whole webpage)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As Corbin commented - you are looking for AJAX tutorial.

Since you've tagged with JQuery starting from [JQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) is a good idea.

Also check out other related questions like - [How to get page content using Javascript or JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933385/how-to-get-page-content-using-javascript-or-jquery)