# Is it possible to read another url's dom structure?

Tags: javascript

Obviously modifying it would be out of the question.

But you would think just reading it should not be a problem?

If i have my .js running on someone's system and I want to analyze the DOM of another URL , client side, is there a way to do this?

Something simple like pull the title tag or pull the url...maybe load the site into an iframe to accomplish this?

Comment: If you're asking whether you can inspect the DOM of a document in another origin, then no.  It would allow stealing user-data in forms, or just served in text.

Comment: The same origin policy prevents you to do that. You can have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414

Comment: Why do you want to do that from a web client instead of a serverside program like a crawler/bot?

Comment: You want to parse a page by javascript ( I mean see the html of it ?)

Comment: document.getElmentbyId().contentWindow.document for the said iframe...I'll figure out the syntax later.

Comment: @CS_2013: `document.getElementById('myiframe').contentWindow.document`.  It was deleted because that won't work if the iFrame is from a different domain than your page.

Comment: @Mic - Thanks I have some hope now.

Comment: @CS_2013, See my answer below

Comment: @Mic - do those methods require control of the other domain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am getting your question right,

A cross domain example by using yql,

```
var url = 'xyz.com'; // website you want to scrape
var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from html where url="' + url + '"') + '&format=json&callback=?';  
$.getJSON(yql,function(data){
    if (data.results[0]){  
        console.log(data = data.results[0].replace(/<script[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/script>/gi, ''));  // The scraped data (the whole webpage)
    }
});
```

Reference: 
[How can i get Equivalent method of HttpwebRequest in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075204/how-can-i-get-equivalent-method-of-httpwebrequest-in-javascript/9075343#9075343)

Comment: yahoo query language...I'm googled out..can you just give me a brief synopsis?

Comment: some sort of yahoo api that does the parsing for you?

Comment: It does a lot of things. 

You will get everything [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/). What it does, how it does, how to do it and more ?

Comment: It acts as a proxy. Since a server can parse any page, it can... and then it sends result back to you as `jsonp`. Since, `jsonp` is cross domain, you can use it from any domain :)

Comment: I don't want to hit another server, though that looks cool there are about 3 different ways to do it mentioned in the comment by Mic.

Comment: SO is saying to avoid discussion. Mark as answer if my answer helped you :)

Comment: Actually...the ways above require access to second origin...your way requires...3rd party.

Answer (score 15):

You can do this using `xmlhttp`

```
function getSourceAsDOM(url)
{
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    parser=new DOMParser();
    return parser.parseFromString(xmlhttp.responseText,"text/html");      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the domains do not match you will not be able to do this due to a security exception. If however you control the other domain, you should research adding a cross domain file to allow access via javascript.

Comment: @SteveBinder: It was deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the html source with a AJAX GET request. An then you can search in the html code or assign it to an iframe/...

Comment: Not if the URL is from another domain.